# Accessing Firebase database from Gupshup

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, gupshup

I am building a bot using Gupshup and Firebase.
 I wish to do two tasks:
(i) I wish to store all my conversations with the users. 
(ii) When the users opens the conversation, I want to fetch the last 10  conversations.

Gupshup supports HTTP GET and HTTP POST methods.

The code for POST method:

```
var url3 = "https://My app name.firebaseio.com/Chat.json";
           var header3 = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
               var param3 = JSON.parse(res).result.fulfillment.speech; // Parsing Result from NLP tool

       context.simplehttp.makePost(url3,JSON.stringify(param3),header3);
```

The code for GET method:

```
context.simplehttp.makeGet('https://My app name.firebaseio.com/Chat.json', function(c,e){
var res = "Sample response from http put method\n"+e.getresp;
context.sendResponse(res);
```

Every time I make a HTTP POST to add data to the Firebase database, a real time is generated under which the data gets added.

Chat:

-KY4yWKeGKIKPf1qf74G:

"hi"

-KY4yWKfjoztU0EBPe1g:

"Hello. How can I help you?"

-KY4ykQtSus8srqa7okF:

"Okay here is the deal: Buy a pizza today and ge..."

-KY4ykQtSus8srqa7okG:

"show some deals"

When I try with HTTP GET https://My app name.firebaseio.com/Chat.json, the following JSON is returned:

```
{"-KY4x81jkuxvT9TjDOfk":"Hello. How can I help you?",
 "-KY4x81kw8zBoaKwAIe-":"hi","-KY4xAQCFDU7SW8PAEHX":"get",
 "-KY4xAR1KEEQNO1KfjnI":"I'm a bit confused by that last part."}
```

Now how can I parse this JSON and access the conversations and present it to users?

Or is there any way to access Child directly using HTTP GET?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    You can use the following way to access the keys and the data:
    //Parse your JSON if you are getting it using http call using JSON.parse(yourjson);

    var json={"-KY4x81jkuxvT9TjDOfk":"Hello. How can I help you?",
     "-KY4x81kw8zBoaKwAIe-":"hi","-KY4xAQCFDU7SW8PAEHX":"get",
     "-KY4xAR1KEEQNO1KfjnI":"I'm a bit confused by that last part."};
   //Getting Keys

   var keys=Object.keys(json);
   //Getting Conversations
   for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
   {
    console.log(json[keys[i]);
   }
```